# pi-hole - syslog messages

Tags: citadel, raspberry

Pi-hole is running fine on my RPI.
However checking the syslog, I see a returning message every 10 seconds.

```
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1]: Started Citadel web service.
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1426]: webcit-http.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1426]: webcit-http.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/webcit/webcit: No such file or directory
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-https.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-https.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-http.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 19 22:25:50 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-http.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 22:25:54 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-https.service: Service RestartSec=3s expired, scheduling restart.
Apr 19 22:25:54 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-https.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 127.
Apr 19 22:25:54 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-http.service: Service RestartSec=3s expired, scheduling restart.
Apr 19 22:25:54 pi-hole systemd[1]: webcit-http.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 127.
Apr 19 22:25:54 pi-hole systemd[1]: Stopped Citadel web service.
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Citadel web service installed on your Raspberry Pi is trying to start the `webcit-http.service` and `webcit-https.service` but cant

If you dont need it, just disable it

```
sudo systemctl disable --now webcit-http.service
sudo systemctl disable --now webcit-https.service
```

if you need it you could reinstall it https://www.citadel.org/installing.html

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. This solved the issue.